# Python/Pandas Find by Id and Match Column Values and Return a Result

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a collection of student answer choices and another dataframe with test answer keys.

```
df1: student grades ( these are what students wrote down as answers)
test id | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3
  1            A            C           D
  1            C            A           A
  2            C            D           D

df2: collection of answer keys (correct answers)
test id | Question 1 | Question 2 | Question 3
  1            A            A           A 
  2            C            D           D
```

I would like to find the question difficulty by looking at percent correct for each question.
To do that I need

1. Match each test by test id
2. Match each student's answer to correct test id answer key and return 1 for right 0 for wrong
3. Count number of right answers and divide by total number of tests for that specific test id

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it this way in pandas:

```
df_student.melt('test id')\
          .merge(df_answers.melt('test id'), on=['test id', 'variable'])\
          .eval('correct = value_x == value_y')\
          .groupby('test id')['correct'].mean()
```

Output:

```
test id
1    0.5
2    1.0
Name: correct, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I just wanted to say that I appreciate your help. I did have to edit the code a little but you did 99% of the work and I actually ended up learning more. Thanks again,

Answer (score 1):

this can be easily be done with two dataframes. You should reorganize your columns though.

**Dataframe1: AnswerKey**

```
Question#   Answer
1           A
2           B
3           C
```

**Dataframe2: Tests**

```
Student      Question#      Answer
x            1              D
x            2              B
x            3              C
y            1              A
y            2              D
y            3              B
```

From there, you can simply join `Tests` to `AnswerKey` on `Tests.Question# = AnswerKey.Question#` and `Tests.Answer = AnswerKey.Answer`. So:

```sql
SELECT      * 
FROM        Tests 
LEFT JOIN   AnswerKey 
  ON        Tests.Question# = AnswerKey.Question# 
  AND       Tests.Answer = Answerkey.Answer
```

From there, you can add two binary columns.

- The first column will be `1` for every row, and it will be your denominator.
- The second column will will be your numerator, and use the logic of:

```
IF      AnswerKey.Question# IS NOT NULL # There was a match
THEN    1
ELSE    0
END
```

the result of your join between these two dataframes will create a third dataframe. To calculate grades by student, you will use the below SQL:

```sql
SELECT      student
            ,SUM(numerator) AS numerator
            ,SUM(denominator) AS denominator
            ,SUM(numerator)/SUM(denominator) AS result
FROM        NewDataframe
GROUP BY    student
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I’ve edited your question to apply formatting. This makes it a lot easier to read. Please review the edits both to make sure they’re consistent with your intentions, and also to learn how to format code on Stack Overflow. (You can click on the clock icon to the left of your post to compare my changes to your previous answer.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I want to clear up few things. The answer key dataframe is a collection of answer keys, not just one test. Also, the other dataframe is a collection of all test that all the students took so far, so not just one student but multiple. What I am trying to do is basically match each test ID to correct Answer Key, then find out if it is correct or not. Then, lastly, do the calculations. Do you have a python solution by any chance? Appreciate your hlep

Comment: That's what the above was doing. Looks like the other guy gave you a Python answer.